# Can not send out pictures that I receive in e-mails. Why?

Tags: email, images, email-client

When I get an e-mail that has pictures in the test, if I try to forward the e-mail, nobody

Comment: Which e-mail client are you using?

Comment: Which OS?, need more info, edit your post to reflect this new information

Answer (score 5):

Under assumption it is Outlook Epxress:

Go to the "Tools" menu > "Options" >  "Security" tab > top of the "Options" window.

Unselect the check boxes next to "Do not allow attachments to be saved or opened that could potentially be a virus" and "Block images and other external content in HTML email."

Hit "OK"

Open the email you want to forward, hit "Forward" button at the top of the window.

Click on "Format" menu at the top of the window and select the "Send Pictures with Message" option.

Comment: You fix enough of the same problems you get hang of it :-)